# How do you install mod_wsgi-4.4.13+ap24vc9-cp27-none-win32.whl to work in Apache 2.4.12 Modules?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, python-wheel

I have this file `mod_wsgi-4.4.13+ap24vc9-cp27-none-win32.whl`  But when I try to use pip to install it via:
`pip install mod_wsgi-4.4.13+ap24vc9-cp27-none-win32.whl`  It responds as it is not a supported wheel on this platform.  Pip is at its latest version.
How do I convert this `.whl` file into the `Mod_wsgi.so` format that Apache will accept?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the official mod_wsgi Windows binaries instead. See:

- https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst